# Table with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to do a onclick function for my table but it's not working i have no clue why
Weapons and Defense was supposed to work like buttons to change the table content but it doesn't work :/
and the content of both Weapons and Defense are shown together
Can u guys give me a hand? thanks

here is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/yorig/braj7sLf/9/

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/mixbasic.css" type="text/css">
        
    </head>
    
    <body>      
        <div id="body">
            <div id="top_box">
                <span class="links_box">
                    <a onclick="Weapons">Weapons</a> |
                    <a onclick="Defense">Defense</a> 
                    
                </span>
            </div>
        
            
            <div id="info_box"></div>
            
            <div id="defense">
            <table id="mix_list_table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

                <colgroup>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                </colgroup>

                <tr class="table_header">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Name</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Effect</td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/lucidy.gif" alt="Lucidy"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sereneo.gif" alt="Sereneo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/fadeo.gif" alt="Fadeo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sparky.gif" alt="Sparky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/raident.gif" alt="Raident"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/transparo.gif" alt="Transparo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/murky.gif" alt="Murky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/devine.gif" alt="Devine"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/celesto.gif" alt="Celesto"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/mirage.gif" alt="Mirage"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/inferna.gif" alt="Inferna"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/enigma.gif" alt="Enigma"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/bellum.gif" alt="Bellum"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/oredo.gif" alt="Oredo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sapphire.gif" alt="Sapphire"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sol.gif" alt="Sol"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="mix1" class="row0" onmouseover="this.className='row_hl';" onmouseout="this.className='row0';" onclick="infoBox(1);">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Transparo Critical Mix</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">MinAP(+3) MaxAP(+4) Crit(+1)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="mix2" class="row1" onmouseover="this.className='row_hl';" onmouseout="this.className='row1';" onclick="infoBox(2);">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Murky Dexterity Mix</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">MaxAP(+6) AR(+45) HP(+10)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr class="table_header">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Name</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Effect</td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/lucidy.gif" alt="Lucidy"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sereneo.gif" alt="Sereneo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/fadeo.gif" alt="Fadeo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sparky.gif" alt="Sparky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/raident.gif" alt="Raident"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/transparo.gif" alt="Transparo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/murky.gif" alt="Murky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/devine.gif" alt="Devine"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/celesto.gif" alt="Celesto"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/mirage.gif" alt="Mirage"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/inferna.gif" alt="Inferna"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/enigma.gif" alt="Enigma"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/bellum.gif" alt="Bellum"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/oredo.gif" alt="Oredo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sapphire.gif" alt="Sapphire"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sol.gif" alt="Sol"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="weapons">
            <table id="mix_list_table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

                <colgroup>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                    <col width="22">
                </colgroup>

                <tr class="table_header">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Name</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Effect</td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/lucidy.gif" alt="Lucidy"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sereneo.gif" alt="Sereneo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/fadeo.gif" alt="Fadeo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sparky.gif" alt="Sparky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/raident.gif" alt="Raident"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/transparo.gif" alt="Transparo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/murky.gif" alt="Murky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/devine.gif" alt="Devine"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/celesto.gif" alt="Celesto"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/mirage.gif" alt="Mirage"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/inferna.gif" alt="Inferna"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/enigma.gif" alt="Enigma"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/bellum.gif" alt="Bellum"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/oredo.gif" alt="Oredo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sapphire.gif" alt="Sapphire"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sol.gif" alt="Sol"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="mix1" class="row0" onmouseover="this.className='row_hl';" onmouseout="this.className='row0';" onclick="infoBox(1);">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Transparo Critical Mix</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">MinAP(+3) MaxAP(+4) Crit(+1)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="mix2" class="row1" onmouseover="this.className='row_hl';" onmouseout="this.className='row1';" onclick="infoBox(2);">
                    <td style="text-align: left;">Murky Dexterity Mix</td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">MaxAP(+6) AR(+45) HP(+10)</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr class="table_header">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Name</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">Effect</td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/lucidy.gif" alt="Lucidy"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sereneo.gif" alt="Sereneo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/fadeo.gif" alt="Fadeo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sparky.gif" alt="Sparky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/raident.gif" alt="Raident"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/transparo.gif" alt="Transparo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/murky.gif" alt="Murky"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/devine.gif" alt="Devine"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/celesto.gif" alt="Celesto"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/mirage.gif" alt="Mirage"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/inferna.gif" alt="Inferna"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/enigma.gif" alt="Enigma"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/bellum.gif" alt="Bellum"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/oredo.gif" alt="Oredo"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sapphire.gif" alt="Sapphire"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/sheltoms/sol.gif" alt="Sol"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

**script**

```
var node = document.getElementById('mix'+id);
    var allNodes = node.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var sheltoms = new Array(
            "Lucidy",
            "Sereneo", 
            "Fadeo", 
            "Sparky", 
            "Raident", 
            "Transparo", 
            "Murky", 
            "Devine", 
            "Celesto", 
            "Mirage", 
            "Inferna", 
            "Enigma", 
            "Bellum", 
            "Oredo",
            "Sapphire",
            "Sol");
    
    var text = "";
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        var s = 2 + i;
            
        if(allNodes[s] != null && allNodes[s].innerHTML && allNodes[s].innerHTML.length > 0)
        {
            text = text + allNodes[s].innerHTML 
                + ' x <img src="images/sheltoms/' 
                + sheltoms[i].toLowerCase() + '.gif" class="box_sheltom_img" alt="' + sheltoms[i] + '"><br>\n';
        }
    }
    
    var infoBox = document.getElementById('info_box');
    
    var name = allNodes[0].innerHTML;
    var effect = allNodes[1].innerHTML;
    
    infoBox.innerHTML = '<div class="box_header"><span class="box_close" onclick="document.getElementById(\'info_box\').style.display=\'none\';">Close</span>Mix Info</div>\n<div class="box_content">'
        + '<b>Name:</b><br>' 
        + name + '<br><br><b>Effect:</b><br>' 
        + effect + '<br><br><b>Sheltoms:</b><br>' 
        + text + '</div>';
    infoBox.style.display = 'block';
    
    
    

}
document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'none';

        
function showCategory(s)
{
    if( s.innerHTML == 'Weapons' )
    {
        document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'none';

    }
    else if( s.innerHTML == 'Defense' )
    {
        document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

**css**

```
#body
{
    /* width: 920px; */
    border: 1px solid #3B2517;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left; /* IE */
    padding: 5px;
    
    background: #554231 url(/images/background.jpg) repeat-x scroll 0px -0px;
}

#top_box
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.links_box
{
    background-color: #3B2517;
    color: #D0B77A;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.3em 0.6em 0.3em 0.6em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid #3B2517;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.selected_link
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D0B77A;
}

.links_box a:link,
.links_box a:visited,
.links_box a:active
{
    color: #D0B77A;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.links_box a:hover
{
    color: #FFF8D9;
}


h1
{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

hr
{
    border: 0px; /* Firefox und Opera */
    border-top: solid 1px #000000;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #E5DAC9; /* IE */
}

table
{
    border-width: 0; 
    border-color: #000000; 
     
    font-size: 1em;
}

td, th
{
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

a:link
{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #34271C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #34271C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #633822;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:active
{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #34271C;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row0
{
    background-color: #F4EBDE;
}

.row1
{
    background-color: #E5DAC9;
}

.row_hl
{
    background-color: #C2AD87;
    color: #000000;
}

#mix_list_table
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #3B2517;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #3B2517;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#mix_list_table td
{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table_header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #3B2517;
    color: #D0B77A;
}

.table_header td
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: default !important;
}

#info_box
{
    display: none;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: #E5DAC9;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left: -225px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 1px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.box_header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #3B2517;
    color: #D0B77A;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}

.box_content
{
    padding: 5px;
}

.box_sheltom_img
{
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
}

.box_close
{
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? There is one. What have you done to try and resolve the error? Always check the error console as your first step in debugging javascript. Is all this code necessary to demonstrate the problem?   Too much code makes it hard to isolate the poblem. In the future please consider a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

I assume this is what you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/2Lasqpnx/

```
function infoBox(id)
{
var node = document.getElementById('mix'+id);
    var allNodes = node.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var sheltoms = new Array(
            "Lucidy",
            "Sereneo", 
            "Fadeo", 
            "Sparky", 
            "Raident", 
            "Transparo", 
            "Murky", 
            "Devine", 
            "Celesto", 
            "Mirage", 
            "Inferna", 
            "Enigma", 
            "Bellum", 
            "Oredo",
            "Sapphire",
            "Sol");
    
    var text = "";
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        var s = 2 + i;
            
        if(allNodes[s] != null && allNodes[s].innerHTML && allNodes[s].innerHTML.length > 0)
        {
            text = text + allNodes[s].innerHTML 
                + ' x <img src="images/sheltoms/' 
                + sheltoms[i].toLowerCase() + '.gif" class="box_sheltom_img" alt="' + sheltoms[i] + '"><br>\n';
        }
    }
    
    var infoBoxArea = document.getElementById('info_box');
    
    var name = allNodes[0].innerHTML;
    var effect = allNodes[1].innerHTML;
    
    infoBoxArea.innerHTML = '<div class="box_header"><span class="box_close" onclick="document.getElementById(\'info_box\').style.display=\'none\';">Close</span>Mix Info</div>\n<div class="box_content">'
        + '<b>Name:</b><br>' 
        + name + '<br><br><b>Effect:</b><br>' 
        + effect + '<br><br><b>Sheltoms:</b><br>' 
        + text + '</div>';
    infoBoxArea.style.display = 'block';
    
    
    

}
document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'none';

        
function showCategory(s)
{
    if( s.innerHTML == 'Weapons' )
    {
        document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'none';

    }
    else if( s.innerHTML == 'Defense' )
    {
        document.getElementById("weapons").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("defense").style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, what i want is when i click on the Weapons the table with <div id="weapons"> is loaded and when i click on Defense swap to table with <div id="defense"> . I'm goting this errors message: <a class='gotoLine' href='#241:27'>241:27</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: Weapons is not defined"
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#242:27'>242:27</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: Defense is not defined"

Comment: Try:
<a onclick="showCategory(this)">Weapons</a>
<a onclick="showCategory(this)">Defense</a>